# How to disambiguate in Clojure

Tags: clojure, cursive

I have this function in a namespace that does not import/require/use any other packages:

```
(defn crash [msg]
  (throw (Throwable. msg)))
```

Cursive (the IntelliJ IDEA IDE Plugin) highlights `Throwable` and gives me the message `Cannot disambiguate overloads of Throwable`. I get the same message with `Exception` and `Error`.

I don't understand the source of this message - I doubt that these Java classes are defined in any other jar files apart from the Java language ones. Anything I can to make this message go away?

These are in the `project.clj`:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [net.mikera/imagez "0.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.4"]]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Throwable` has two 1-arg constructors ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)): one expecting a `String` and the other expecting a `Throwable`.

At runtime Clojure figures it out (since, in this specific case, it's impossible for an object to be both a `String` and a `Throwable`) but this requires the use of reflection.

Adding a type-hint to `msg` to specify which overload you expect to use would remove the need for reflection and hopefully calms Cursive down.

```
(defn crash [^String msg]
  (throw (Throwable. msg)))
```

Comment: Both the diagnosis and the solution are correct here - I should probably make that message friendlier. Cursive tries to warn whenever interop will require reflection using the same logic as the compiler.

Comment: @Colin could you list the candidate overloads?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the tooltips occasionally got extremely large. I'll try it again and see if I can work around that.