# Why is Clojure unable to infer this def type?

Tags: clojure, type-inference, cursive

I was writing a client/server test, and ran into something unexpected. In the following code, the port argument of the `Socket` constructor isn't able to be inferred:

```
(ns second-try.test.client
  (:import [java.net Socket]))

(def port 5555)

(defn -main []
  ; "Cannot disambiguate overloads of Socket"
  (let [sock (Socket. "127.0.0.1" port)]))
```

The type of the first argument should be obvious since I'm passing a literal. I would think the type of the port would be obvious too since again, it's just a literal; albeit one tucked away behind a `def`.

For some reason though, it can't figure out the type of `port`. I can remedy it by putting an annotation on either the `def`, or in front of the argument, but why is this necessary? Shouldn't it be obvious to it what the type is?

Comment: What can't figure out the port? The code runs fine on my machine. If the problem is with Cursive see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472894/how-to-disambiguate-in-clojure).

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I am using Cursive, so that could be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really possible to infer the type of the value stored in a var in Clojure, because a var can be re-defined at any time.

However, Clojure shouldn't have any problem determining the type at run-time and, although it will require the use of reflection to disambiguate at run-time, the code in question should (and does) run.

The error appears to be related to Cursive:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32473508/440294

> Adding a type-hint ... to specify which overload you expect to use would remove the need for reflection and hopefully calms Cursive down.

In your case, I'd try something like:

```
(defn -main []
  ; "Cannot disambiguate overloads of Socket"
  (let [^int p port
        sock (Socket. "127.0.0.1" p)]))
```

Comment: That makes sense. I've never redefined a `def` before, so I never thought about it being an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean for 'p` to be passed to the constructor?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yes, I meant for `p` to be passed to the constructor.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, just declare you var to be `:const`:

```
(def ^:const port 5555)

(defn -main []
  (let [sock (Socket. "127.0.0.1"  port)]))
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks.